# In its former, pre-burnt-out life, was this thing a capacitor?

Tags: identification

I've a problem with a ventilation system that stopped working shortly after power-on. I've pulled out what I believe is the power supply board and I can see an obvious problem, but I'm not entirely sure what the component is near the center that set on fire. Physically it seems virtually identical to a blue disc-shaped, two-legged one on the far left of the board between U4 and U3. That component is labelled C15, and the burnt out one is labelled RV1. Is there any hope of identifying the damaged one or do I need a manufacturer schematic to know the specifics (E.g. capacitance)?

[image]

[image]

And a closeup with flash:

[image]

Edit: couple of additionals

[image]

[image]

Edit2: my neighbour has an identical unit. I was able to photo his board without disturbing it, alas no markings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: RV typically stands for varistor, and the shape hints to it too. BTW, be aware that (other) components may not *look* damaged, they still *can be* damaged.

Comment: C5 does seem to have popped its top.

Comment: Also check the diodes in that bridge ... they can fail dead short when other bad things happen.

Comment: Keep in mind that when components die, they either have died from something that's harmed the components connected to them, or they took out other components as they died.  One burnt component on a board usually means more than one dead or sick ones.  So check carefully, and hope it's not a design problem.

Comment: Clean the carbon off with alcohol and you may be able to see the part number etc.

Comment: Traced a possible cause; a wiring mistake elsewhere meant that this board ended up powered through a Z-wave remote control lighting dimmer, probably delivering a low output (I believe it's triac based but don't know details). It seems the dimmer is also burnt out/nonfunctional..

Comment: @bruceabbot alas, there are no markings on it..

Comment: @TimWescott sometimes that is true, other times components just fail due to age or external influences and the device is fine after they are replaced. Especially surge and interference suppresion components connected directly to the mains have a hard life and often fail in older equipment.

Comment: If you replace the MOV, make sure to clean all the black soot... carbon is conductive.

Answer (score 6):

It almost certainly was an MOV, Metal Oxide Varistor, a type of transient suppressor.  It is on the AC side of a bridge rectifier, next to wires marked Line and Neutral, and next to an AC-rated film capacitor (the yellow box) that is part of the power line input noise filter.  All of this points to primary-side protection.

In the center photo, the signal path is from the input wires, left through the fuse, up to the first layer of capacitors (both line-to-line and line-to-earth), right through common mode choke L1, then through another layer of capacitors, then down through the bridge rectifier.

If the supply is a universal-input type, then the MOV is rated for something in the 270-300 Vac range.  The physical size determines how large a transient it can absorb.  You can get approximately the same protection by matching its diameter.

Comment: By universal input do you mean accepts 120 to 250v? The sticker on the unit says 220-240- might that explain why running it on a triac dimmer(don't ask) caused a failure?

Comment: 220-240 is not a universal input range, but the high end of one.  If the input were the low end only (100-120 or so), then you could use a 130 V MOV and get a higher suppression capability for a given package size.  Also, I don't think a TRIAC dimmer caused the failure.  MOV's suppress a few transients well, but do not fully recover.  With each hit their characteristics change, sometimes to the point that they are conducting a small current constantly.

Answer (score 2):

### - after looking at the creapage clearances in the layout, it’s not up to code or zero margin at best. scrap it.

Grid fault transient blew up your AC MOV clamp with only a CM filter choke to limit current.

Better designs have DM or higher inductance differential mode chokes to limit current.

- so these  10 us transients at >1kV to 6kV have the voltage that is filtered and does not reach the unprotected over  voltage since then clamp level kicks in across  line or to earth. but if The current limit in the choke is not enough, it breaks-down, arcs across and burns up.
- when the MOV breaks down it safely absorbs a certain number of Joules by rating.
- but if the voltage rises faster to exceed breakdown rating, then the coil arcs and then follow on current of the grid until zero crossing can/willburn a hole in the board.
- this design might have been passed but your incident level was worse.
- it can be repaired with new MOV’s , and test parts and diode bridge, but I doubt it will be done 1st try.
- all bulged e-caps are dead and maybe IC’s
- florida users see this with substandard PS products often.

Answer (score 1):

"RV" probably refers to a [varistor.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varistor)

They are used to protect equipment from over voltage coming in through the power supply.

Yours is in the area of the connection to line voltage - the green, blue, and brown wires there close by.

It seems your varistor has given up its life to protect your equipment.  It's hard to tell if it was successful or not.  Varistors are intended to catch transient events (short peaks of voltage beyond the the normal line voltage.)  As burned as yours is, that "transient" seems to have been a rather long event - the rest of the circuit may have been damaged when the varistor burned through.

C5 (the electrolytic capacitor by the blue wire) looks to have taken some damage as well.  The top should be flat, but it appears to be bulged in the picture.  Electrolytics that fail usually bulge their lids.

The first thing to do is to find out why there was such a prolonged high voltage event on the power line.

Once you find and fix that, you can remove RV1 and replace C5.  The circuit can operate normally without RV1, though it will be unprotected against the kind of thing that killed the first one.

Comment: I think you're right about that cap too!

Comment: The first question to answer is "what caused the varistor to fail?"  They don't usually just up and die - something has to kill them.

Comment: they do just up and die. every impulse damages them until they fail.

Comment: @Jasen: Yeah, but in that case they usually just fail open and don't provide protection any more.

Comment: they usually fail closed until something explodes, (often it's the wire in a fuse)

Comment: ...but _sometimes_ they just get a partial short and burn slowly.

Answer (score 0):

My similar power supply burned up that component too.  My burned up, leftover disk measured 10mm; a similar power supply that I opened for comparison had a 15mm item in that location labeled NTC 5D-15 which is a 5 ohm thermister rated for 6 amps.  I surmise the 10mm zombies on my board were 5D-10 (3 amp) of the same item, two of them, wired in parallel.

[NTC 5d thermistor and how to use it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/378868/ntc-5d-thermistor-and-how-to-use-it)

I learned on the above posting that this thermister, in this circuit, is an in-rush current limiter that goes to 5->0 ohms in a few seconds.  It does indeed come first in the circuit (see the third pic below that shows the heat signature under the thermisters, but also shows that they were connected to the neutral 'line in' terminal).

My board was in a new installation providing LEDs with 12vDC.  I had 30 meters of LEDs with sales info of 1A/m, but that seemed high to me and I expected it to be less although I hadn't measured it.  The Power supply was rated for 33 amps (400W).  On my PS there was a hot smell in just a few minutes and it failed completely in a few hours (why I left it on, Nooo one Knoows!).  My board also showed heat under the Bridge Rectifier.  I do not think the load of the LEDs caused the heat in the bridge rectifier because the 40A power supply that I opened to find what it was that failed (the thermisters) has that same bridge rectifier in the nominally same circuit and it has been running the load for several weeks while repair parts were on order so the bridge rectifier itself (rather than too many LEDs) may be the source of the overcurrent on the Thermisters... or it may be something else.

I have received a pack of NTC 5D-15 and one of GBU-808, the bridge rectifier (in case it was the 'problem').  I will put in the (larger) thermisters and replace the bridge rectifier, and will run it under very light load and see. 
I'll get back to you I hope.

[image: Previous location of Thermisters][image: Chineese Power Supply, 12V 33A][image: Heat signature under the thermmisters][image: Heat signature under the Bridge Rectifier]